# debugging a signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am attempting to debug a signed apk running on a real device... and when I say debug, I mean do things like add breakpoints and single step - I don't just mean view the log output.

Looking at other similar questions it appears that I need to display the DDMS view and then somehow attach the debugger to the process, but I am confused for two reasons.

1. I can not see a list of processes under my real device (though I do see a list of processes if I start up an emulator). **[this bit now solved - see comments]**
2. even if I did have the list of running processes running, how could I set a breakpoint in the source before actually running the app? How could eclipse possibly even know what  source corresponds to the apk??

I guess I'm missing something here? Is there a blog article or similar that could guide me through the whole process?

For the record my device is already configured to allow USB debugging and I do see log messages from my signed-apk-app.

Comment: If I guess right is the problem that a signed app is optimized and serveral debug informations are removed and also a signed app should have the attribute `android:debug="false"` in the manifest.

Comment: @rekire: Ok, I added android:debuggable="true" to my manifest and made a new signed apk. Now I DO see my apps process listed under my device name and I can click on it to "debug" it... but then how do I actually get to see the corresponding code that is being executed? How do I add a breakpoint?... is the debugging process somehow different to the debugging process when launching an (unsigned) app directly from eclipse?

Comment: I never tried to debug a signed app, why don't you try to debug a normal debug build?

Comment: because I'm debugging some in-app purchase code which can not possibly work without the apk being signed.

Comment: Ah that's a good reason. Sure that you cannot register the debug certificate for that api? I know the Maps API (in the Android 1.x times) was able to do that.

Comment: I've never heard of the concept of "registering a debug certificate for an api"... so that looks like a tricky route to take!

Comment: this is a very good question, i need an answer to this too

Answer (score 1):

With the comments I figgered out that you are trying to debug in-app purchase code. For that you don't need to use the real certificate. You could also use the debug certificate. So register the debug certificate and use that *debug* api key.

So you can debug the app as you already know it.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to "register the debug certificate".. I'll report back later.

Comment: I tried researching how to "register the debug certificate" here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222247/signing-apks-what-does-it-mean-and-how-do-i-do-it/ and ran into problem (take a look). What I want is "source code debugging".